# Pycharm strange warning when type hinting

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Pycharm behaves strange, warns for `get_list_1` but not `get_list_2`

**Code**

```py
import typing
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


def get_list_1() -> typing.List[datetime.datetime]:
    return [x]


def get_list_2() -> typing.List[int]:
    return [x]


print(get_list_1()[0])
print(get_list_2()[0])
```

**Why does Pycharm complain?**

> Problem synopsis      Expected type 'Integral', got 'Union[datetime, datetime]' instead (at line 7)

*Pycharm version 2016.1*

Comment: Restart your `Pycharm`

Comment: Report a bug on the PyCharm issue tracker.

Comment: Restart did not change this

Comment: Reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19222