# How to get warnings for wrong return types in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

In a Python 3.7.1 project a method is defined with return type incompatible with the result type. However, the IDE,  PyCharm 2018.2, gives no warnings. Here's a code example:

```python
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing

# Definitions:
@dataclass(order=True)
class Theta:
  vector: np.ndarray

def a(self) -> typing.AnyStr:
    return self.vector.size

def b(self) -> str:
    return self.vector.size

# Client code:
x = np.array([1, 2])
s = Theta(x).a().capitalize() # runtime errors
u = Theta(x).b().capitalize()
```

Is there a way to enforce type warnings, both in the definitions and the client code?

*Note:* There're several questions about Python type hints on SO, e.g.,  [Pycharm strange warning when type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662069/pycharm-strange-warning-when-type-hinting).  However, they seem to focus on a different aspect.

Answer (score 0):

`typing.AnyStr` is a type variable. It means that it will be inferred from passed parameter or containing class. In your case neither class, nor method does not use this type variable and as a result inferred `a` return type is `Any`.

Comment: What about the other method, with signature `-> str`? It's the same situation with type warnings.

Comment: @Tupolev._ Ctrl+click on `size` will open `size` definition where you could see that there is no mention about type of `size`. Type hints https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs are under development at the moment.